# Union of preimages

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Given $f:X\rightarrow Y$ as a function, the **image** of $x$ if $f(x)$. The **preimage** of $y$ is $f^{-1}(y)=\{x\ |\ f(x)=y\}$, with the symbol **PreIm$(Y)$**

Given the definition, could you prove the following statement? Thank you.

Given that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function, and that $A, B \subseteq Z$.

**PreIm$(A\cup B)$** = **PreIm$(A) \cup$ PreIm$(B)$**

Comment: Try doing a search; you should be able to find a variety of proofs of this statement already on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Note the discrepancy in your notation, you define **preimage** for elements of $y$ but then **PreIm** is defined for sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Of course, you are familiar with the standard abuse of notation identifying $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, I'm sure

Comment: @MPW The definition using "$\{ x\mid f(x)=y\}$" doesn't apply for subsets of $Y$ though, that's what OP is suggesting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: And, in fact, I suppose it is the very result OP wants to prove that allows the extension from points to sets. Point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please dispense with the silly notation "**PreIm()**". The standard notation is $f^{-1}(\cdot)$.

That said, one notes that $f^{-1}$ is generally well-behaved.

If $x\in f^{-1}(A\cup B)$, then $f(x)\in A\cup B$, so either $f(x)\in A$ or $f(x)\in B$, which means $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ or $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, hence $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$. We have shown $$f^{-1}(A\cup B)\subset f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B).$$

If $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, then either $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ or $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, so either $f(x)\in A$ or $f(x)\in B$, so $f(x)\in A\cup B$, hence $x\in f^{-1}(A\cup B)$. We have shown that $$f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)\subset f^{-1}(A\cup B).$$

Thus
$$
\boxed{f^{-1}(A\cup B) = f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)}
$$
as desired.